# Another name for sub-sub-group

Tags: word-choice

I have a group that is named "Service Group". Within that service group, there are service sub-groups. Within those service sub-groups, there is another level down. Is there another word that is better than "Service Sub-Sub-Group"? I wanted to avoid using level 1, level 2, etc. since *sub-group* sounds more intuitive.

Comment: One way to handle this problem is by not referring to everything as a "group." For example, you could call it the "Service Division"; then, you might divide a Division into Sections, and then divide Sections into Groups (or whatever nomenclature you want to use).

Comment: its a sub of another sub-group hence a sub-sub-group: stick with it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using different names for each level of the hierarchy. For example, instead of calling it the *Service Group*, you might call it the *Service Division*. 
A *Division* could be divided into *Branches*, *Branches* into *Sections*, *Sections* into *Groups*, and *Groups* into *Teams* (or whatever nomenclature you want to use).

Answer (score 3):

I think the word you're looking for is tertiary, of the third order, rank, stage, formation, etc.; third.

You'd have the group, the sub group and the *tertiary* group.

Comment: I should have said the same thing @rudra said. I don't know know why that answer was downvoted.